# iOS: Playing Audio via Bluetooth

Tags: avaudioplayer, avaudiosession

I'm struggling when trying to get my application's audio to play via Bluetooth.

I have set up my `AVAudioSession` in my `AppDelegate` like so:

```
    AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord, withOptions options: .AllowBluetooth)
```

However, when I have my `AVAudioPlayer` instance play audio in my application while my device is connected to my automobile's Bluetooth audio system, it connects as though it is making a cellular connection for a voice call.

I've read the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Audio/Conceptual/AudioSessionProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html) for configuring an `AVAudioSession` for playing audio, which I have working when not connected to Bluetooth, but I'm still not sure where to go from here.

Any suggestions on where I should be looking?

My application is very simple, and it only plays audio based on what the user wants to listen to, which can be a combination of audio files being played by separate `AVAudioPlayer`s. There is no need for audio input to the device.

Comment: Did you try going to your "capabilities" tab an turning on "Audio, Airplay, etc.." as well as "Acts/Uses Bluetooth accessory)

Comment: @MikeG That was it! I had one checked, but not the other.

Comment: swift 5: AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(.playAndRecord, mode: .default, options: .allowBluetooth)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to go to your "capabilities" tab and make sure to have box selected for, "Audio, Airplay..." as well as "Acts/Uses Bluetooth Accessory"